# Issues while converting HTML to master in SP Design Manager 2013

Tags: 2013, branding, design-manager

I converted my html file to master page successfully and it gives me following message on preview page:

> your master page doesn't have any warnings or errors.

But when I browse "Edit Master Pages" from design manager it is giving following message against my html:

> Warnings and Errors.

Secondly, I am not able to see the new master page in drop down for selecting it as a default master page in site settings.

Any one faced this issue before, whats a way out of this

Comment: Have you made sure the generated master page is actually checked in and published?

Comment: that made my master page to appear in drop down but first issue is still appearing, though it is not causing any problems but still want to know its reason.

Comment: Normally you can get more information than just "warning and errors" by clicking the text, but not sure with generated files